# Nested Request with Bloc Pattern

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get familiar with the Bloc pattern and make for myself a bittrex App to check what happens with my coins.

I'm trying to render a list of owned coins. Like;

- BCH x 1.56 (Highest:0.076, Lowest:0.069, Now:0.75): $ 1,238

The problem is that I have to make two requests to get all the information. First request to get my coin balance (all owned coins) and the second one for getting the ticker (lowest highest price for the last 24h).

My Bloc has a Stream `<List<BalanceModel>>` which filled on the Bloc construct.

My goal is to load the list of all my coins and show that circular loading bar where the ticker will be displayed. To achieve that, I add 2 additional Streams

1- `PublishSubject <MarketSummary>`

2- `PublishSubject<String>`: It takes the coin-index like 'BCH' and the handler function makes the ticker request and pushes the result (MarketSummary) into the first sink which will actually be rendered on the view.

But unfortunately(actually its the way how a stream acts), the stream pushes all the summaries (one after another) and at the end all coins have the same ticker information.

What would be the best way to solve the problem? My ideas;

- I'm thinking of a WrapperModel which have both models as variables but it is somehow ugly.
- Using the pub-sub (with an additional control on the view layer when the stream fires a new marketSummary)
- A foreach loop after I got my coins, to make the ticker request for every coin. It requires a wrapper model (which holds coin and ticker) and I have to wait a long time before I can show anything on the view.

Comment: One way is your `Stream` should represent a `List<MyModel>` rather than a single object and then you can map the list and filter by id from ui side

Comment: Or the model where you store ticker information becomes a field under `BalanceModel`